# Is this proof of $\bigcup (A \cup B) = \bigcup A \cup \bigcup B$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I've recently been studying some set theory from the book Elements of Set Theory by Herbert Enderton. This is one of the exercises.

$\bigcup \cal{A} := \{x:(\exists a \in \cal{A})x\in a\}$

Theorem:

$\bigcup (A \cup B) = \bigcup A \cup \bigcup B$

Attempt at proof:

$x \in \bigcup (A \cup B) \iff (\exists X \in A \cup B)x \in X $

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \iff \exists X[(X \in A$ or $X \in B) \implies x \in X]$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \iff  \exists X [(X \in A \implies x\in X)$ or $( X \in B \implies x \in X)] $

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \iff (\exists X \in A)x \in X$ or $(\exists X \in B)x\in X$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \iff x\in \bigcup A$ or $x \in \bigcup B$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \iff x\in \bigcup A \cup \bigcup B \ \square$

I'm not sure if the third line is correct, is it? Also is the fourth line equivalent to:

$\iff (\exists X \in A)x \in X$ or $(\exists Y \in B)x\in Y$ ?

I would think so, since as far as I know we should be able to replace any variable defined in this way with any other in a statement like $\exists A \varphi (A)$.

Comment: I don't think I like any of those $\implies$. I think they should be $\text{and}$s.  And then I think it is fine.  Except you miswrote the last line as what you started with.  Yes the fourth line *is* equivalent to $(\exists X\in A)x \in X$ or $(\exists Y \in B)x\in Y$ which in turn implies $x \in \bigcup A$ or $x \in \bigcup B$ and so $x \in \bigcup A \cup \bigcup B$.

Comment: @fleablood They look weird to me too. At the same time I'm not convinced that I can just replace an 'if (P or Q) then R' statement with '(P and R) or (Q and R)' (Is that logically sound?). I've corrected the last line.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think in the existance statement, is of the form: (Something exists of a type)such that this true.   I don't the you want to say $\exists X [X\in A \text{ or } x\in B]\implies x\in X$ which is saying "There exist an $X$ such that if $X\in A$ or $X\in B$ then $x \in X$. (Logically that *might* technically true but...).  I think what you want to say is "there exists and X where $X\in A$ or $X\in B$ such that $x \in X$. and I that that is written $(\exists X| X\in A \text{ or }X\in B)x\in X$.  (then I think you can go directly to the fifth line skipping the 4th altogether.

Comment: The second and third line are wrong: you can always take an $X$ that is neither in $A$ nor in $B$, making those statements always true. Just delete them and the argument works again.